# is it possible to decrease swap partition space in centos7

Tags: centos, swap, partition, cwp

Some of my friends told me that larger swap partition is very bad like thousands of web hits/min should be possible on my server,

The swap space is 16 GB, and i installed centos7 with ["CWP" -> Control web panel](http://centos-webpanel.com/)

with enable csf, should i consider decrease swap partition space if it possible without formatting the server and how? or there is a solution to maintain this space not to harm the server,,

```
    [root@server ~]# df -h
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on 

devtmpfs         16G     0   16G   0% /dev 

tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm 

tmpfs            16G  201M   16G   2% /run 

tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup 

/dev/sda2       1.8T  256G  1.5T  15% / 

/dev/sdb1       1.8T  275G  1.5T  16% /backup 

/dev/sda5        16G   83M   15G   1% /tmp 

/dev/sda1       969M  187M  716M  21% /boot 

tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/0 

tmpfs           3.2G     0  3.2G   0% /run/user/1075 

[root@server ~]#
```

Comment: May you give a look to this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/303483/how-to-reduce-swap-partition

Comment: Yes, I saw it, but my partitions are not LVM and i think i can't use gparted on centos7 it need graphical environment.

Answer (score 0):

I found that swap file i more effective and easier to do in my case, so i disabled the swap partition and created a swapfile instead..

[Here](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2018/08/how-to-use-swap-file-instead-of-swap.html) how you do it exactly.

[image]